# Inconsistent values in tags

Tags: bug

I want to report a bug that I have seen a lot in `Data Science` community. Whenever you track your **Next tag badge** in your dashboard, it does not get updated. When you click the tag name, you see inconsistent values.

[image]

And after clicking the tag:

[image]

I have seen this problem a lot.

Comment: You probably should show a picture or two to illustrate what you mean, as the current description is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @StephenRauch is that fine?

Comment: For a bug report should probably also list Browser and OS.  Have you tried other browsers?  Although I have trouble envisioning how the browser version would be related to the pop up thing.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm using Chrome and it's up-to-date and yes, I got the same result using Edge.